# Should Dashboard be included in breadcrumbs as homepage?

Tags: navigation, breadcrumbs

When users press on site logo, or when they login, they land on **Dashboard**, which is considered as homepage. They can go to other sections of the system from the sidebar menu - Messages, Events etc. Those sections can have their own subsections.

When users go to other pages, should **Dashboard** be included in breadcrumbs as parent page, or is this separate independent section?

---

### Option 1. Dashboard as parent section

[image: Dashboard as parent]

---

### Option 2. Dashboard is separate section

[image]

Comment: Is it a webapp, website or mobile app?

Comment: @RobE This is website

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question about breadcrumbs and I will **differ** on the answer offered in this question [Should 'Home' be included in website breadcrumbs?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21662/should-home-be-included-in-website-breadcrumbs?rq=1)

I would ask yourself this question - **Is there the use case where a user  enters the site from the events page (if a users bookmarks that page and always enter from there, for instance)?**

**If the answer is yes,** then having Dashboard as the initial breadcrumb can break the logic of the user. Since they have not originated from that spot. Thus, you should go for option 2.

**If the answer is no,** then I would follow the answer given by GotDibbs in the above cited question.

Answer (score 0):

Nielsen Norman group says:

**Start breadcrumbs with the Home link.**

Breadcrumbs tell people their current location while offering one-click access to the higher site levels. The best practice is to start the breadcrumb trail with the Home link as it represents the highest level.

**If your site shows breadcrumbs, don’t show Home in the site’s main navigation.**

There’s no need to offer Home links in both breadcrumbs and the site’s navigation. Having the same link twice on the same page is a bad idea because it increases complexity needlessly.  Duplicating links is one of the four major dangerous navigation techniques that cause cognitive strain.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/homepage-links/

Comment: I'm not sure that NNG's advice is good advice. The article cited is based on a very old article that is *arguable* at best. In nowadays responsive design with multiple possible screen sizes, you never know if two elements are close together or not. And accessibility principles (or simply the principle KISS ) recommend having both, just in case. Having two "home" links is no more cognitive burden than not finding the home link.